# jquery: Put separated arrays in an array without concating them

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an input which can as below:

```
"a"
```

or

```
  ["a","b"]
```

or

```
  [["a","b"],["c"]]
```

the target is to convert them to third pattern. I mean I need a big array, contains multiple arrays. 
as pseudo-code, I try as below:

```
  input=[].concat(input);
  for (var t in input)
   {
     t=[].concat(input);
   }
```

but it does not work for second pattern, since I want `[["a","b"]]`.

```
"a"=>[["a"]]
```

and

```
  ["a","b"]=>[["a","b"]]
```

and

```
  [["a","b"],["c"]] => [["a","b"],["c"]]
```

Comment: please add to the three inputs the expected outputs as well.

Comment: I did it, so please answer if it's possible for you. tnx.

Comment: That's because `[["a","b"],["c"]]` is an array inside of an array. to access it you would need to use `t[0]` and look through that array to get to `a`,`b` Example `var a=[["a","b"],["c"]]` -  `a[0][0]` => `a`  / `a[0][1]` = > `b` /  `a[1][0]` => `c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if the given value is an array and if the inner item is an array as well and if not, then wrap the value in an array.

```js
function convert(v) {
    if (!Array.isArray(v)) {
        v = [v];
    }
    if (!Array.isArray(v[0])) {
        v = [v];
    }
    return v;
}

console.log(convert("a"));                 // [["a"]]
console.log(convert(["a", "b"]));          // [["a", "b"]]
console.log(convert([["a", "b"], ["c"]])); // [["a", "b"], ["c"]]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you need to test every item of the inner array, then you could check first all items.

```js
function convert(v) {
    if (!Array.isArray(v)) {
        v = [v];
    }
    if (v.some(function (a) { return !Array.isArray(a); })) {
        v = [v];
    }
    return v;
}

console.log(convert("a"));               // [["a"]]
console.log(convert(["a", "b"]));        // [["a", "b"]]
console.log(convert([["a", "b"], "c"])); // [[["a", "b"], "c"]]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows;

```js
var inputs = ["a", ["a","b"],[["a","b"],["c"]]],
    result = inputs.map(a => [[].concat(...a)]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```